# Директива валидации для сравнения полей

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день. Такой вопрос. Как правильно на ангуляре сделать директиву для валидации сравнение введенных данных (если они равны - хорошо, не равны - дизейбл кнопки). Мой вариант почему-то не работает..

JS

```
 function personalController($scope, personalService) {
$scope.changePassword = function () {
    $scope.oldPassword;
    $scope.newPassword;
    $scope.confirmNewPassword;

$scope.myCompare = function() {
   return angular.equals($scope.newPassword, $scope.confirmNewPassword);
}; }

angular.module('appPersonal').directive('equalPass', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(equalPass) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('equalPass', $scope.myCompare());
            });
        }
    };
});

    angular.module('appPersonal')
.controller('personalController', ['$scope',   'personalService',personalController]);
```

html

```
  <input ng-model="confirmNewPassword" type="password"  placeholder="confirm new password" name="confirmNewPassword" required equalPass><br>
                <span ng-show="recoverPassword.confirmNewPassword.$error.equalPass" class="text-danger">New password and confirm password mast be equals!</span>
```

Comment: `myCompare` - описана в скопе, а вызываться пытается как просто функция

Comment: почему решили использовать парсер, а не $validators?

Comment: дописал scope для myCompare. решил использовать парсер потому что нашел похожий пример в гугле...так не правильно?

Comment: `$scope` - у вас же параметр `scope` на `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

Одна из вариаций на тему, здесь используется `$viewChangeListeners`, можно развивать тему дальше, [работающий пример на codepen](http://codepen.io/diproart/pen/WxbqoX)

```
(function () {
   angular
    .module('app',[])
    .controller('AppController',['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.user = {};
    }])
    .directive('samePassword', SamePasswordDirective);

   function SamePasswordDirective() {
     return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: link,
      scope: {
       samePassword: '='
      }
   };

  //////////////////

  function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function () {
      ngModel.$setValidity('samePassword', 
        scope.samePassword.$modelValue === ngModel.$modelValue);

      scope.samePassword.$setValidity('samePassword',
        scope.samePassword.$modelValue === ngModel.$modelValue);
    });
  }
}
})();
```